# Extracting data from an Array in Powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell, sorting

I populated an array using the following:

```
forEach ($ip in $ipReturn.IPAddress) {
   try {
      $jsonObject = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri "https://api.weatherchannel/forecast/daily?ip=$ip&days=2&units=I&key=$apiKey" -Headers $header 
      $jsonDataArray += $jsonObject
    }
    catch {
        $errorTrap = $error[0]
        Write-Host "Status Code:" $_.Exception 
        Write-Host "Status Description:" $_.Exception 
    }
}
```

I have the following data populated in an Array in PowerShell:

```
$jsonDataArray | foreach{Write-Host $_}
@{timezone=America/New_York; city_name=Azalea Park; lon=-81.3004; data=System.Object[]; state_code=FL; country_code=US; lat=28.5535}
```

I need the data located in each array piece. Particularly: `data=System.Object`.

I had thought to use the following structure:

```
$foreach (system.object['data'] in $jsonDataArray)
{
    //pull and extract all data as string objects and populate those strings into a new array. Search each array string and pull data to create histogram.

}
```

I have looked through code. Does anyone have an idea how I can achieve this data extraction?

Answer (score 3):

Don't let the type of the `data` field distract you :)

```
foreach($jsonData in $jsonDataArray)
{
    foreach($data in $jsonData.data)
    {
        # $data represents each object in the data array
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok so - I did a test with the following: 
  foreach ($jsonData in $jsonDataArray)
{
        foreach($data in $jsonDataArray)
            {
                Write-Host $data
            }
}   and the output still shows as @{timezone=America/New_York; city_name=Druid Hills; lon=-84.3604; data=System.Object[]; state_code=GA; country_code=US; lat=33.8181} .  In this case data = System.Object and thats the data I need. So I am not sure how to extract each object and pull that data out.

Comment: @WT Notice in my example, the _inner_ `foreach` loop iterates over `$jsonData.data`, not `$jsonDataArray`

Comment: Oh wow! Thank you so much Mathias. I really appreciate the help!